# UIWebView's loadHTMLString method doesn't work well with online javascript?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I use `loadHTMLString` method to load a HTML string.

```
self.webview.loadHTMLString("the html", baseURL:nil)
```

the html's content like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p> Tap me to hide</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The result didn't work well. The javascript code didn't execute. But when I change `<script src="http://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js">`
 to a local one and give a proper `baseURL`, it will work well.

Comment: Could this be because you are using an `http` URL to fetch your remote JavaScript? By default, iOS 9 does not do remote `http` (has to be `https`).

Comment: Yes, it's about `https`. But I test on an iOS 8.4 device, it require `https` too.

Answer (score 1):

As @matt mentioned, it's about `https`.

Remote JavaScript must be a `https` one. when I change the script to `"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"`, it worked.

I test it on iOS 9/8.4, UIWebView / WKWebView, they all require `https`.